# how to send a key stroke window message to a hwnd through JNA

Tags: windows, jna

I am just wondering if anyone could please give an example of sending a key press window message to a given hwnd using JNA. I tried to use `SendMessageA` but it did not work at all.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[`SendInput()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310%28VS.85%29.aspx) is the officially sanctioned way to fake input.  The limitation is that it sends input to the window that has input focus which may not be what you need.

Another option would be to send a `WM_SETTEXT`, or similar, if the target window responds appropriately.

Exactly what the best option is will depend on exactly what type of window you are targetting, which you have not said.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I intended to send a key press to a window that is not currently in focus. I was trying to send a message using WM_KEYDOWN. Would either WM_KEYDOWN or WM_SETTEXT work for this purpose? Could you post some code snippet? Thanks again!

Comment: how about you tell us what kind of control is the target?

Comment: how about just the notepad window? I am not sure if JNA is about to obtain sub-controls given the window's handle.

Comment: If you want to add text to Notepad find the handle of the edit window and send it edit control messages. But is it really Notepad that you are interested in?